# Messed up Gnome files, how do I reset them?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I was messing with my gnome to change the classic purple Lock Screen and accidentally changed something in the usr folder that I wasn’t supposed to and I get the “Oh no! Something has gone wrong” screen when trying to boot with gdm3 or sddm (not the case with lightdm). I uninstalling:

- ubuntu-gnome-desktop
- gnome-shell
- ubuntu-desktop
- gdm3

,then installing them again with nothing changing.

———————————————————

System info:

Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad 5 14''

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4600U with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 2.100GHz

AMD ATI 04:00.0 Renoir

OS version: Ubuntu 21.04 x86_64

Thanks to all those that help!

Comment: theme file you edited is a gresource or css?

Comment: The file was css

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 and you edited css file, Ok.. so what is the theme name that you edited? did you install User Theme extension?

Comment: I edited the Yaru-dark (dont remember the exact file), I didnt install uses theme extension.

Comment: Is there a way for me to reset the changes I did in the directory?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. It is possible to bring back normal behaviour, did you edit gnome-shell theme or gtk theme?

Comment: I think you have edited gtk.css or similar.. try to run this command from any TTY `sudo apt install --reinstall yaru-theme-gtk`